# get specific string pattern from string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

im trying to parse an email and get out the value of a specific parameter out of it.

there's quite a few links in the email so i think the easiest approach is to search the entire text for the string i need.

now this will appear twice in the email in exactly the two formats:

```
&param_id=xxxxxxx<
&param_id=xxxxxxx&
```

the only different is the trailing character.  it doesn't matter which one is parsed, whatever is easiest.  all i need is the value of the XXXXXXX

X is a sequence of numbers and NOT a fixed length.

Comment: So, you want all values of a specific param_id from links or want to filter entire link?

Comment: just the values of param_id from a single link.  it appears twice in the email text, and it will be the same for both.  i put both instances in case it would make it easier to get one over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should help

```
Regex reg = new Regex("param_id=(?<param_val>[0-9]+)");

            MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(str);

            foreach (Match item in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Groups["param_val"].Value);
            }
```

Comment: Will that return the XXXX without the trailing `<` or `&`?

Comment: I think, you are running foearch on Match object, not the MatchCollection.  reg object return both reg.Match() and reg.Matches.  Please use second method.

Comment: yeah you were right, im changing it up to only get one result, but i think it's working.  one second to verify and ill mark your answer